# CSS IE8 Photos are hidden

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

In my gallery I have thumbnail images that sit in an unordered list. For some reason they do not display in IE8. Could anyone explain why?

[www.melbournedodgeball.com.au/dodgeball2012/photos](http://www.melbournedodgeball.com.au/dodgeball2012/photos)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use clearfix this method, add this code

```
<ul class="clearfix gallery"> 
   <li></li>
</ul>

.gallery ul li {width:223px; float:left;}
.gallery ul li a {width:100%;}
```